# iOS how to check if go to the bottom of webView

Tags: ios, webview

Is there any event I can notify the supper view?

I try the scrollViewDidScroll. But it don't be called.

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll: (UIScrollView*)scrollView
{
    NSLog(@"At the bottom...");
}
```

Comment: is webview delegate set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must set the delegate of scrollview which in the webview to `self` first. So that, `scrollViewDidScroll:` could be call when you scroll the webview. So, try this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.webview.scrollview.delegate = self;
}

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView*)scrollview
{
    CGPoint offset = scrollView.contentOffset;

    CGRect bounds = scrollView.bounds;

    UIEdgeInsets inset = scrollView.contentInset;

    CGFloat currentOffset = offset.y + bounds.size.height - inset.bottom;

    if (currentOffset - scrollView.contentSize.height <= 0)
    {
        NSLog(@"At the bottom...");
    }
}
```

Comment: And another question: how this event can notify the super view?

Comment: @JasonWu You could call the superview's some method which predefined to notify it. And you could notify the super view using NSNotification. Or notify the super view using delegate like UITableView's delegate.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an instance of webView, you can get the reference of its scrollView by doing,
`webView.scrollView`. Set its delegate to `self` like so:

`webView.scrollView.delegate = self;`

Now, make sure you have implemented `UIScrollViewDelegate` in your class where you have an instance of the `webView`. Implement the below the code that tells you whether you have reached the bottom.

```
 - (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
        float bottomEdge = scrollView.contentOffset.y + scrollView.frame.size.height;
        if (bottomEdge >= scrollView.contentSize.height) {
            //This means that you have reached the end.
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the call in scrollView delegate methods you need to assign the delegate for webview scroll view like this:

```
webview.scrollView.delegate = self;
```

Also Conform the UIScrollViewDelegate in .h file like this:

```
@interface MyController : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate>


@end
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is interested on how this is done in Swift 4, here it is:

1. Set the webviews' scrollView delegate to self in viewDidLoad()    `self.webView.scrollView.delegate = self`
2. Extend your class from UIScrollViewDelegate
3. Implement the method scrollViewDidScroll() which will handle the scroll events
   (this particular implementation is used to check if the user has scrolled to the bottom of the webview's content)

   ```
   func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
     let bottom = scrollView.contentOffset.y + scrollView.frame.size.height
     if (bottom >= scrollView.contentSize.height) {
       // Do something here
     }
   }
   ```